# IIS Sql Server Timeout issue

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, web-services, iis-7

I have a a stored procedure which searches a view and takes in two parameters. When I run it in Management Studio it takes exactly a second to run. When I run it through an IIS Webservice hosted on the same network I get an SQL time out error.

The problem is it doesn't time out every time and sometimes dropping and recreating the view jump starts the process but not every time.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have connection pooling set up? If your pooling is not configured well you might find your self with a closed connection. Or you can try to manually open and close the connection to your database.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/angelsb/archive/2004/08/25/220333.aspx